# How can I change the CSS style of a page depending on the screen's width?

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, responsive-design

I'm making a website and I need the website to be responsive, so I need to change the CSS depending on the width of the screen. I have 3 stylesheets, a main, normal and mobile version, that are present in the HTML:

```
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="stylesheet/main.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="stylesheet/style.css" media="(min-width: 851px)" type="text/css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="stylesheet/mobile.css" media="(max-width: 850px)" type="text/css" />
```

When I use this, I always make sure that it works by changing the width of the page, and I see that it works. However, when I use Chrome's Emulation mode (inspect element -> enable emulation), and the screen is below the maximum width for a certain stylesheet, the webpage conservs its "normal" mode and my responsive design doesn't have any effect. Should I be using this in the CSS instead (as one big file):

```
    @media only screen and (max-width : 851px) {}
```

Normal (on big screen): [image: normal]

When I change the width (big screen): [image: mobile on big]

emulation mode (ipad): [image: glitch???]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use media queries. See e.g. this page https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries

Answer (score 3):

Your method, although not wrong, is less than ideal. I usually have the same problem when I come across websites that employ this method.

Instead, make 2 stylesheets

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="stylesheet/main.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="stylesheet/responsive.css" />
```

Make sure the responsive.css is below the main.css so that it overwrites the main css if needed.

Do all your responsive breakpoints in that stylesheet.

It is probably a good idea to use a responsive framework (Bootstrap) this minimizes the amount of responsive code you will be doing as long as you make use of the bootstrap classes that are available to you. And it is much easier to maintain.

If Bootstrap doesn't have the breakpoints you are looking for, I'd suggest you look into SASS + Susy [link](http://susy.oddbird.net/)  With Susy, you can map your breakpoints in anyway you want and you can nest your media code within the element you want to behave responsively. Neatest method and the future of front end design.

Comment: Thanks! How can I make sure that one stylesheet ovewrites the other though?

Comment: The bottom stylesheet will overwrite the top one. "IF" by any chance you have a stubborn property that is not overwriting due to CSS specifities, use !important to overwrite. However, use sparingly, because you are making that the highest authority.

Comment: I would prefer using specificity to over write something, rather that using !important. Look up CSS Specificity Rules

Answer (score 2):

While you can use 2+ stylesheets as mentioned above - you can prevent the extra HTTP request by using one, and placing:

`@media only screen and (max-width : 851px) { /* Responsive rules here */ }`

at the bottom of the stylesheet.